# extract substring from string given in list

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, tidyverse, stringr

I have two tibbles, one with some series codes of uneven length, and one with country codes

```
codes <- as.tibble(c("brcomec", "frcomopf", "decombwf", "ezcomop", 
       "jpcomop", "aewheob", "ezcompis", "decomipf"))
countries <- as.tibble(c("br", "fr", "advecos", "af", "africa", "al", "dz", "as", "ad", 
                     "ao", "ai", "aq", "ag"))
```

How do I extract the countries from "code" given the information in countries, i.e. I wish to have something like

```
dta <- data.frame( 
~country , ~ rest , 
br       , comec  ,
fr       , comopf ,
...
)
```

I tried with `filter(str_detect(code, paste(countries)))` but this did not work out, so any help is kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```
library(tidyverse)
codes1 <- substr(codes$value, start = 1, stop = 2)
codes2 <- substr(codes$value, start = 3, stop = 10)

codes3 = tibble(codes1, codes2)
codes3
```

Which returns this?

```
# A tibble: 8 x 2
  codes1 codes2
  <chr>  <chr> 
1 br     comec 
2 fr     comopf
3 de     combwf
4 ez     comop 
5 jp     comop 
6 ae     wheob 
7 ez     compis
8 de     comipf
```